# Maximal submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I wonder if the notion of "maximal submanifold" exists or is relevant? I'm surprised because I found pretty much nothing about it on the web (after a quick search).

The definition, which seems natural to me, would be something like: Let $M$ be a (smooth, say) manifold. A maximal submanifold in $M$ is a connected submanifold $N$ (smoothly embedded, say) such that there is no other connected submanifold $N'$ of $M$ such that $\dim N' = \dim N$ and $N'$ strictly contains $N$.

Comment: According to such a definition any closed submanifold is  maximal. So for example in the riemannian case any compact manifold only has noncomplete nonmaximal submanifolds

Comment: Sure. But some "maximal submanifolds" are not closed (thus incomplete), which makes "my" definition not irrelevant, it seems.

Comment: @Seub: Do you know any examples of noncompact maximal manifolds?

Comment: @studiosus: what about a line in the plane? But maybe you want an example where $M$ is compact, in this case I'm thinking about something like a non-intersecting curve accumulating on a circle or something for both ends (on the sphere for instance)

Comment: @Seub: Neither line nor plane are maximal with your definition, as line is diffeomorphic to the open interval, and, hence, line properly contains itself! Same for the plane. On the other hand, maybe by 'other' you mean nondiffeomorphic?

Comment: @studiosus: you have not understood the definition properly. Being "maximal" is a property of a *sub*manifold in a manifold. A line is maximal as a submanifold of a plane. (I might add that containing oneself after a diffeomorphism hardly makes any sense)

Comment: @Seub: I see, I indeed misunderstood the definition. However, what I do not understand then is the motivation. Your notion is related, but is different from, to two standard topological/geometric concepts: A complete Riemannian submanifold and a proper embedding. Both are standard and quite useful. In contrast, I do not see how you would use the maximality concept and what questions you would ask. One question I can think of: Is there an open manifold $M$ so that every embedding $M\to N$ to any target manifold, is a maximal submanifold. Clearly, this is impossible in dimension 1...

Comment: I think, I can prove that such $M$ cannot be 2-dimensional either (this requires the classification theorem for open surfaces of infinite topological complexity due to Brown and Messer). I have no idea about higher dimensions.

Comment: The motivation is pretty transparent to me, it just seems like a natural concept. But for instance, to be more concrete, I'm thinking of maximality being relevant when talking about integral submanifolds (satisfying some sort of differential equations), generalizing maximal solutions for ODEs with integral curves (I'm thinking about Frobenius theorem for instance).

Comment: @Seub: when talking about ODEs the relevant idea is called a *foliation* of the manifold, sometimes people also talk about singular foliations, and further degenerate notions like *laminations* of manifolds.  In foliations, the closest thing to what you're interested in is called a *leaf* of a foliation.

Comment: Sure sure. A foliation leaf is an example of a "maximal submanifold" as defined above.

Comment: I think that's why people don't bother giving this notion a separate definition.  If you're interested in ODE solutions, you have the foliation terminology.

Comment: OK, I guess. But it still seems to like a general and natural concept to me (the reason I wanted to use it was not about ODEs and foliations in fact)